Settings missing in repo in github
We have just moved to github and I am a member of an organization and have the role Member. Within there I am working on a repo. I am missing the settings menu any suggestions why that is? Is related to my role, the plan or?

All help is appreciated.I need the menu to access variables for the repo.

The reason is that you don't have right permission. To access the Settings tab, you need to have Owner role of the organization repository. To get more information, please check it: Roles in an organization
